# Display Overlay on Radio Button Image using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to display an overlay onto my radio button images. So far I can create a border for the selected image but I cannot get a background image to overlay in front.  Here is my code:

HTML/AngularJS:

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="size in sizes">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_size" ng-model="$parent.currentSize" value="{{size.value}}" hidden/>
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{size.url}}">
            <img class="overlay" src="images/greenCheck.png">
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ .img-thumbnail {
    border: solid limegreen .3em;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:7%;
    height: 15%;
    background: url("images/greenCheck.png");
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is what I have currently:
Before I click on a radio button.
[image]

After I click on a radio button.
[image]

> I want the check marks to only appear when selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the opacity for the overlay to 1, when the radio is checked:

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ .img-thumbnail {
    border: solid limegreen .3em;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:7%;
    height: 15%;
    background: url("images/greenCheck.png");
    opacity: 0;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .img-thumbnail + .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This makes for a great possibility to make a transition for the checkmark to fade in, adding a `transition` to the `.overlay`, as the overlay is already in place just hidden, and when adding `opacity: 1;` the checkmark will fade in, if there is specified a transition.

Comment: @Freddy05 just wondering why you chose this over simply adding the selector to the already-existing css rule?

Comment: In my response, you can add a transition on the opacity only. Thats why I would do it this way, at least.

Comment: I am not sure of the already-existing css rule, I am new to css.  Could you explain further?

Comment: @Freddy05 I mean that you don't have to add a new CSS rule, just make a small change to the one you already have... take a look at my answer (the first one posted time-wise)  to see what I mean.

Comment: There were no requirements in the question for transition, so the simplest answer based on what was given is just to add the same selector that is already in use. I live by the KISS principle :)

Comment: I used this one because when I used yours I still had to create a separate rule to initialize the background image.

Comment: I tried both changes and this one was the perfect fit. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the `input[type=radio]:checked` selector to your `.overlay` too, i.e.:

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ .img-thumbnail {
    border: solid limegreen .3em;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* .overlay { */                          // <- change this....
input[type=radio]:checked ~ .overlay {    // <- ...to this
    position: absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:7%;
    height: 15%;
    background: url("images/greenCheck.png");
    opacity: 1;
}
```

With your current code, you are displaying the overlay all the time, not just on selected images.

Edit: You don't need to include the image here - you already include it in your CSS so its included twice.

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="size in sizes">
        <input type="radio" name="radio_size" ng-model="$parent.currentSize" value="{{size.value}}" hidden/>
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{size.url}}">
            <span class="overlay"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This works although I would still have to keep my .overlay rule, if I remove my .overlay rule the checks take over the space in my page and cause many more problems.

Comment: @Freddy05 You've chosen the other answer and thats fine, but I'm just really confused about what you mean here - the check is only added in your overlay rule, so  if you remove it them surely that would also remove the check?

Comment: @Freddy05 Ah now I see the problem - you are including the check image twice, once in your HTML  and once in your CSS. You can remove it from the HTML (or the CSS) altogether, otherwise you are just duplicating it :)

Answer (score 0):

my css:

```
label > input{ 
 visibility: hidden; 
 position: absolute; 
}
 label > input + img{ 
 cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
 }
label > input:checked + img{ 
border:2px solid #f00;
}
```